# Get $('#id').attr('src') for background image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the background image in a div using jquery. I tried

```
var img = $('#id').attr('src');
```

but

```
alert(img)
```

shows up as null / undefined.

I tried this too `document.getElementById('elementId').src;` but same result.

I also tried this `var img = $('#outer').css('background-image');` shows up as url(s/bg.jpg)

What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you want the background image (as in, image set by css `background`) or an actual image tag?

Comment: Weird how you had an extra question (which you should have put as an edit to your original question) and then accepted the answer not addressing that extra question.  This website is more than a platform for you asking questions; it's also a reference!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to get a style property using `css()`

Try

```
var img = $('#id').css('backgroundImage');
```

Comment: shows up as url(s/bg.jpg)

Comment: And that's exactly what you want, not?

Comment: and that is what would be expected as that's how background images are defined

Comment: need to get it as s/bg.jpg

Comment: well you will have to parse the result... what are you trying to do?

Comment: The correct solution was provided by Ionică Bizău

Comment: @X10nD  Why did you accept this answer, while the one by Ionică replies to all your questions?  I don't know either but the accepted answer is also use as a reference for future viewers of this question!

Comment: @Dominique I got the first reply from charlietfl and I had another issue that was resolved.  It was related to the initial query itself. Bottom line is to get what I want.

Answer (score 5):

`background-image` is a CSS property, so use the `.css` method:

```
var img = $('#id').css('background-image');
```

The call above will return the *computed style property* (containing `url(path)`). To remove the `url` part use a regex replace:

```
img = img.replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, "");
```

You can do it one-line as follows:

```
var img = $('#id').css('background-image').replace(/^url\(|\)$/g, "");
```

---

> ### [`.css( propertyName )`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)
>
> Get the computed style properties for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: I'm afraid you're missing some brackets.  I haven't tested it but it's kinda dangerous not telling jquery what function to execute first... it's far from fail-safe!

Comment: @Dominique I tested it. ;-) `$('#id')` is the first call, returning the jQuery object. `css(...)` is the second call (a method of the jQuery object returned by the first call) -- this returns a string, supposing the element exists. `replace(...)` is the third call using the string returned by `css`. Is it clearer? :-)

Comment: Of course it is... and it should work... but I had some nasty experiences in the past with jquery so I started using extra brackets as a fail-safe.  Maybe the later versions of jquery got better at it but in the past I can assure you the logic was lost from time to time. But hey, if what you wrote works then there's no need for the brackets... I would still use them though, but that's just me... I don't trust jquery much further than I can throw it.

Comment: @Dominique It's not a jQuery thing but JavaScript. But I agree there are cases when additional brackets make the code clearer.

Comment: @X10nD Yeah, since you asked how to remove `url(...)` from string and I replied, I don't feel very well to have this feedback.